# Bulleted List does not show on pages

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I'm able to use bulleted lists in item detail descriptions but not on any page content or category content. Code seems fine.

and so on ending in

I can place numbered list in but have to add another  to get it to move over.
Not critical but I like bullets better.
Example page where coded for bulleted and does not bullets. First bullet at Using hydroelectric and so on.
http://www.deckandrailings.com/about-us/

Thanks..............

Comment: how solved your error

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Theme issue with Ultimo.

[image: bullet fix in Ultimo]

Comment: this is my code, <ul class="bullet">
<li>Sri Krishna</li>
<li>sri krishna&nbsp;pooja</li>
</ul>   not working